# apache POI merge cells with data resulting in data loss

Tags: java, apache-poi

We are displaying a number and a percent like "2 (100%)" in  each cell.
I would like to apply different formatting to the Number part and percentage part. It seems not possible to apply different formatting, within a cell.

So I'm trying to write data into 2 consecutive cells, which have different formatting and then merge it.

But after merging , the data in the second cell is lost. 
How can I merge, with both cells data merged to single cell ?

```
HSSFFont percentFont = wb.createFont();
percentFont.setFontName(HSSFFont.FONT_ARIAL);
percentFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 10);
percentFont.setBold(true);
percentStyle.setFont(percentFont);
for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
    List<String> rowData = rows.get(i);
    int rowNumber = 9 + i;
    HSSFRow row1 = sheet.createRow(rowNumber);
    int colNumber = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
        HSSFCell hssfMainCell = row1.createCell(colNumber);
        HSSFCell hssfPercentCell = row1.createCell(colNumber + 1);
        hssfPercentCell.setCellStyle(percentStyle);

        String val = rowData.get(j);
        String percentage = "(" + rowData.get(percentageColumns.get(j)) + "%)";
        ;

        hssfMainCell.setCellValue(val);
        hssfMainCell.setCellStyle(rightAligned);
        if (percentageColumns.get(j) != null) {
            hssfPercentCell.setCellValue(percentage);
            percentStyle.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);
            hssfPercentCell.setCellStyle(percentStyle);
            sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(rowNumber, rowNumber, colNumber, colNumber + 1));
            colNumber++;
            colNumber++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do either of these things in Excel, either - you can't apply different formats to parts of a cell value, and you can only have one value for the merged cell. Your best bet is to set the desired value as text, formatted programmatically, as you won't be able to use Excel formats for this case

Comment: Can you please tell, what you mean by setting formatting programmatically?

Comment: Meaning that you'll assemble the exact value you want to see (e.g., `2 (100%)`) in your Java code (like `String val = rowData.get(j) + " " + "(" + rowData.get(percentageColumns.get(j)) + "%)"`), and set the cell type to text

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @AlexSavitsky.